# Generic JSON Serialization for multiple types

Tags: json, scala, playframework, play-json

I'm building a Play API that calls a SOAP Service. That's the only communication mechanism that our provider given to us. That service returns a list of *"Packages"* as follows:

```
<packages>
  <package>
    <!-- Cardinality: 
          "metadata" : 1 (required),
          "types" : 0-n (zero or more occurences),
          "options" : 0-n (zero or more occurences)-->
    <metadata>
      <id>1</id>
      <subid>1</subid>
      <name>Package 1</name>
    </metadata>
    <types>
      ...
    </types>
    <options>
      ...
    </options>
  </package>
  <package>
    ...
  </package>
  ...
</packages>
```

The service returns a generic structure of packages, but, for our API consumer that approach doesn't work, so, our API will return a JSON with all the Packages qualified, as follows:

```
{
  "packages" : {
    "package1" : {
      "metadata" : {
        "id" : "1",
        "subid" : "1"
      },
      "types" : [
        {
          ...
        },
        ...
      ],
      "options" : [
        {
          ...
        },
        ...
      ]
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

So, in Play we've defined our model like this:

```
trait Package

trait PackageTypeA extends Package{
  def metadata: PackageMetadata
  def types: List[PackageType]
  def options: List[PackageOption]
}

trait PackageTypeB extends Package{
  def metadata: PackageMetadata
  def options: List[PackageOption]
}

trait PackageTypeC extends Package{
  def metadata: PackageMetadata
  def types: List[PackageType]
}

sealed case class Package1 (metadata: PackageMetadata, types: List[PackageType], options: List[PackageOption]) extends PackageTypeA
sealed case class Package2 (metadata: PackageMetadata, options: List[PackageOption]) extends PackageTypeB
sealed case class Package3 (metadata: PackageMetadata, types: List[PackageType]) extends PackageTypeC
```

We know that we have, roughly, six or seven types. For the sake of clarity i'm including three. Note that some of that types only have "options" and some only have "types" and two specific cases have both of them.
We use the trait `Package` to generalize our construction and the concrete case classes for every kind of Package.

So, the only way to identify the Type of a Package is through `id` and `subId`, both present in the Package metadata. For build our structure we've created a function for every concrete type that returns that type (function taking the generic `PackageDTO` return a `Package1` object, function taking the generic `PackageDTO` return a `Package2` object and so on), return our function and evaluate the conditions to determine the kind of the Package:

```
//PackageDTO is the structure returned by the SOAP Service. 
private def fPackage1(p: PackageDTO): Package1 = {
    val metadata: PackageMetadata = buildMetadata(c)
    val types: List[PackageType] = p.getPackages.toList map {
      package =>
        buildBackage(package)
    }
    val options: List[PackageOption] = c.getOptions.toList.map{
      opt =>
        buildOption(opt)
    }
    Package1(metadata, types, options)
  }

  private def fPackage2(p: PackageDTO): Package2 = {
    val metadata: PackageMetadata = buildMetadata(c)
    val types: List[PackageType] = p.getPackages.toList map {
      package =>
        buildBackage(package)
    }
    Package2(metadata, types)
  }

def f[A >: Package](p: PackageDTO): PackageDTO => A = {
    if ("1".equals(p.getMetadata.getId) && "1".equals(p.getMetadata.getSubId)) fPackage1
    else if ("2".equals(p.getMetadata.getId) && "2".equals(p.getMetadata.getSubId)) fPackage2
    else fPackageN
}

def transform[A >: Package](p: PackageDTO)(f: PackageDTO => A): A = {
    f(p)
}
```

So, we call our transformation function like this:

```
transform(c)(f(c))
```

And we get (for all Packages) a `List[Package]`. Our real problem starts here...

**PROBLEM**

We've all the JSON Readers/Writers for our types: `PackageMetadata`, `PackageType`, `PackageOption`, but, since we cannot write a reader/writer for a Trait (`Package`) we can't convert our `List[Package]` to our desired JSON structure.

**QUESTION**

Is there any *"generic"* way to transform our `List[Package]` into a JSON Structure in where we can know every type of package? Having (Package, Package, ...) get (Package1, Package2, ...) in a JSON structure as we've specified previously.

I think in Shapeless and HList but i can't figure it out how to change the approach to use it.

Thanks in advance!